# ES2015 - What are the downsides to using static methods which new up a constructor on every call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, static, ecmascript-6

I am writing a simple ORM / wrapper for [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) and there are two approaches I am trying to decide between.

The first approach is just a regular class which must be instantiated before use:

```
class Base {

    constructor() {
        this.db = db;
    }

    all() {
        return this.db(this.table);
    }

    find(id) {
        return this.db(this.table).where('id', id).first();
    }

    // more similar methods...

}

class User extends Base {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.table = 'users';
    }

}

// calling code
let user = new User();
user.find(1).then(user => console.log(user));
```

The second approach, which I am more inclined to use, uses static methods which create the instance:

```
class Base {

    constructor() {
        this.db = db;
    }

    static all() {
        const model = new this;
        return model.db(model.table);
    }

    static find(id) {
        const model = new this;
        return model.db(model.table).where('id', id).first();
    }

}

// calling code
User.find(1).then(user => console.log(user));
```

I like the static approach because the API is cleaner (no instantiating necessary) but I am not familiar with what the drawbacks are. So my questions are is this a good approach or not? And if not, why? Is there a third option that lies somewhere in the middle that would be better?

Comment: where is the `db` coming from?

Comment: Very relevant: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/) – Static calls are hard coupling code and prevent dependency injection. That's the same in any language, and the same problems arise from it in any language.

Comment: First approach is fine enough! U can not access 'this' in static function.So if u want to call a static function,u should pass 'this' or other data by arguments

Comment: db is coming from a require at the top 
`const db = require('../database/connection');` So testability and DI are the drawbacks? And you can access this inside the static as I am doing with here: `static create(props) {
        const model = new this;
        return model.db(model.table).insert(props).returning('id').then(id => this.find(id[0]));
    }`. That method works fine.

Comment: I recommend the object oriented approach for different reasons, maybe later you can have some more type of  ``User`` , ie ``SuperUser`` or ``Student`` that can make use of the methods of the the parent class, I would use the static method only for generic functions

Answer (score 0):

how about this if you wanna avoid objects?

```
class Base {
  constructor() {  }
  static all() {
    return db(this.table())
  }
  static find(id) {
    return db(this.table()).where('id', id).first()
  }
}

class User extends Base{
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  static table(){
    return 'users'
  }  
}

// calling code
User.find(1).then(user => console.log(user));
```

this would work, but I don't this is good way to do things, for starters, `Base.all()` would throw error, also if all your class methods are going to static, you might as well use plain js objects like:

```
let Base = {
    all: function(){ 
      return db(this.table)
    },
    find: function(id){
      return db(this.table.where('id', id).first()
    }
  }
  , extend = (a,b) => {for(let i in b) a[i] = b[i]}
  , User  = {table: 'users'}

// calling code
User.find(1).then(user => console.log(user));
```